# how do you store 100s of different select names and their selected options in a object as a key value pair

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a table of dynamic data which is echo'ed out on the webpage in a table format as shown in the picture

LINK FOR THE IMAGE: https://ibb.co/RCYwchv

so the table will have a lot of select tags with different names and values depending upon how much (applications are there ) iteration takes place!

```
foreach($data['applicationList'] as $applications){
  echo '<td><select name='.$applications['aid'].'>
  <option value=000>Reject All<option>
  <option value=111>Accept All<option>
  <option value=100>Accept 1st Choise<option>
  <option value=010>Accept 2nd Choise<option>
  <option value=001>Accept 3rd Choise<option>
  <option value=110>Accept 1st and 2nd Choise<option>
  <option value=011>Accept 2nd and 3rd Choise<option>
  <option value=101>Accept 1st and 3rd Choise<option>
  </select></td>
}
```

Is there any way i could capture all the different selected values and names which are changed and bind them to an object of key value pair to send it to the controller using javascript or jquery ajax? Could someone help me on this!

Comment: No, no one can help you on this! You haven't described your problem well!

Comment: @JayBlanchard there is how do you store 100s of different select names and their selected options in a object as a key value pair! thats the question i have!

Comment: @JayBlanchard sorry English is not my language still learning.. thank you for the comment.. could you please show me an example.. so i can try working im still in school learning not as experienced...

Comment: I cannot show you an example because I do not know what it is you're trying to do. Please give us a clear example of what you expect to do.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wish to gather all those values each time they change...

So you nee a `change` handler which will loop through all the `select` elements and add their key/value to an object.

The example below should be instructive to you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // This code part is just for this demo...
  // I needed to recreate multile select elements.
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    var clone = $("[name='someName']").clone();
    
    // Setting a different name for each
    var newName = clone.attr("name")+i;
    clone.attr("name",newName);
    $("body").append(clone);
  }
  
  
  // Now to get the values each time one is changing
  var data_obj = {};
  $("[name^='someName']").on("change",function(){
    $("[name^='someName']").each(function(){
      data_obj[ $(this).attr("name") ] = $(this).val();
    });
    
    // Result
    console.log( JSON.stringify(data_obj) );
  });
});
```

```css
select{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name='someName'>
  <option value=000>Reject All<option>
  <option value=111>Accept All<option>
  <option value=100>Accept 1st Choise<option>
  <option value=010>Accept 2nd Choise<option>
  <option value=001>Accept 3rd Choise<option>
  <option value=110>Accept 1st and 2nd Choise<option>
  <option value=011>Accept 2nd and 3rd Choise<option>
  <option value=101>Accept 1st and 3rd Choise<option>
</select>
```